# How do I connect my Pi to a wifi that requires a Username and Password?

Tags: wifi, headless

I'm fairly new to the Pi and am trying to connect it to my University's wifi. I am unsure how to get it to run solely on wifi which requires both username and password (vs just SSID and pass). I've gotten it to work when connected to an ethernet cable, but have been unsuccessful just using wifi alone. Any tips/resources would be appreciated.

Comment: The OP says repeatedly s/he's  trying to connect on wifi.  Whether the password and username are needed for eth is a bit irrelevant, unless you are trying to find out whether there is a captive portal, in which case you should just ask, "Do you need to go to a web page and log in first?".

Comment: I don't see any reason to believe there's such a portal, the OP just needs to fill in a `wpa_supplicant.conf` (I think there's a GUI method now).  In any case, Libbie, this a question that has been asked a thousand times before, there is no need for someone to spend time explaining it online *yet again* unless there is some complication or something you do not understand -- in which case you should ask a more specific question (eg., you say you "have been unsuccessful" but nothing about what exactly you tried and what, in detail, happened).

Comment: Does your university use [eduroam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eduroam) WiFi? @goldilocks If this is true it has nothing to do with setting up static IP address in Pi OS. eduroam uses **Protected EAP** (PEAP) authentication. [See an example for Ubuntu set up here](https://servicedesk.rose-hulman.edu/knowledgebase/article/KA-01010/en-us).

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/31507/proper-configuration-for-wpa-supplicant-conf) about PEAP configuration.

Comment: *"it has nothing to do with setting up static IP address in Pi OS"*  Couldn't agree more.  It has to do with connecting to a secure WLAN with DHCP.   That is pretty much a default scenario, you just have to provide the details (SSID and password).  If such is not the case, and the duplicate question does not solve the problem, then the OP needs to provide details about that.  Right now there is really nothing else to go on.

Comment: [Edit your question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/136189/edit) and teell us if your University uses `eduroam` or PEAP authentication for WIFi. Without this information this question cannot be reopened.